# выполнение pdo mysql запроса из функции

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

я изучаю oop и хочу использовать pdo для запросов к базе данных. у меня есть запрос который находится в функции, но я не знаю как к нему обратиться, получаю ошибку

> Fatal error: Call to a member function exec() on a non-object in

что я делаю не так?

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

function testDuplicate($model) {
    $SQL = "SELECT product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product WHERE model LIKE '" .$model . "'";
    $result = $conn->exec($SQL);
    if ($result->rows) return false;
    return true;
}

foreach ($xml->PRODUCT as $child) {
    if (testDuplicate($child -> ID)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: А какой был смысл задавать  тот же вопрос на английском СО?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объявите `$conn` глобальной внутри функции и используйте подготовленные выражения

```
function testDuplicate($model) {
    global $conn;
    $SQL = "SELECT product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product WHERE model LIKE :model";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($SQL);
    $statement->bindValue(':model', $model);
    $statement->exec();
    return $statement->fetchColumn();
}
```

Comment: downvote из за ответа Razzwan глобальные переменные зло

Comment: @Naumov С этим я даже согласен. Однако, не будьте настолько фанатичны. ООП не панацея

Comment: Не панацея я даже непротив global но новичок может начать фанате, так что думаю стоит как то сдержаваться с этим, в конце концов подключение передавать через параметр.

Comment: Если честно я бы вам за конструкцию `return ($statement->fetchColumn() !== FALSE);` минус бы поставил ещё один.

Comment: @Naumov Чем она вам настолько не понравилась? Просто привел к булевому значению (хотя конечно можно было и не приводить). Ничем не хуже вашего `if ($result->rows) return false; return true;`

Answer (score 3):

Переменная `$conn` внутри функции не существует. Ее туда нужно либо передать в качестве аргумента, либо, как посоветовали в предыдущем варианте, объявить что `$conn` внутри функции - это глобальная переменная.

Первый вариант мне кажется более предпочтительным, т.к. использование глобальных переменный внутри функции - это неявный функционал и может в будущем привести к сложностям восприятия и отлавливания новых ошибок.

Comment: спасибо за объяснение :)

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю, что ответы уже есть, но лучше это классом сделать, где-то так:

```
class Db {
    private $con = null;

    // если уже есть конект не подключать снова
    function getCon() {
        if (!is_null($this -> con)) {
            return $this -> con;
        }
        $this -> con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $this -> con -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $this -> con;
    }

    // ну и собственно вывод функции
    function testDuplicate($model) {
        $SQL = "SELECT product_id FROM ".DB_PREFIX. "product WHERE model LIKE '".$model. "'";
        $result = $this -> getCon -> exec($SQL);
        if ($result -> rows) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не очень удачный пример класса. А точнее сказать - очень неудачный. Класс DB не должен выполнять запросов к конкретным таблицам. Плюс сам код скопированный из вопроса попросту не будет работать.

Comment: @Ипатьев Если брать MVC согласен, но ни кто об mvc неговорил... Да и име класса выбранно для примера.

Comment: Если имя класса будет другое, то в нем, очевидно, не должно быть никакого соединения с БД. Да и мвц здесь не при чем. Вопрос был задан про соединение с БД. И решать его, создавая инстанс ПДО в каждом объекте приложения - это убивать сервер.